# Disable Hot Code Replace for the Eclipse Java debugger

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, hotdeploy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable Hot Code Replace in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594408/how-do-i-disable-hot-code-replace-in-eclipse)

When you change Java code while in a debugging session, Eclipse will upload the updated class files into the running JVM (hot code replace). This even works for remote applications.

Is there a way to turn Hot Code Replace off (within Eclipse, not at the remote JVM)?

We want to be able to debug our test and staging servers remotely, but prevent unintentional updates to the builds that they are running.

Comment: This question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594408/how-do-i-disable-hot-code-replace-in-eclipse

Comment: The top answer on the linked duplicate is about how to disable the *warnings when replace fails*, not the actual replacement (and the question did ask that). I don't think this is properly a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527613/disable-jvm-hot-swap is more closely related and arguably a duplicate of this.

Comment: Thanks for the question. I have just discovered that hotswap works even with remote debugging

Answer (score 5):

[Here they say](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_hot_code_replace%3F), that if HCR does not work, you may have 'automatic building' turned off.

So, maybe just switching off automatic building for debugging solves your problem.

Comment: good point, that is a valid workaround.