# How do I disable Hot Code Replace in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

HCR is failing a lot more often than not for me at the moment. It keeps popping up the "Hot Code Replace Failed" dialog, over and over and over. I know there is a checkbox to shut it up, but later on when I'm doing something else I actually want the dialog to appear. Plus I don't want hot swapping code right now anyways, I just want the debugger.

So is there a setting someplace for that "do not show dialog again" checkbox, for when I want to re-enable it? Better yet, is there a way to turn HCR on and off period?

BTW, as far as I can tell disabling "Build Automatically" doesn't disable it.

Answer (score 19):

Window / Preferences -> Java / Debug

There are four checkboxes related to Hot Code Replace. Disabling them all should help you.

Comment: This does not disable hot code replacement itself, only the warnings for when it fails.

Answer (score 2):

An update on Paulo Guedes's answer:

Eclipse Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0) has an 'Enable hot code replace' checkbox under the Hot Code Replace section of Preferences->Java->Debug (dont select any of the sub sections under the reveal arrow beside Debug, it is the top level of Debug that you want).

Comment: Cool, but I want to disable it for specific launche configurations only. I guess that's not possible?