# Hot Code Replaced Failed

Tags: android, eclipse

I keep getting the below warning message in eclipse when doing Android development. No matter how many times I click the option to not show the warning again, it just keeps popping up. Sometimes I hit disconnect, sometimes I hit continue, but either way the warning keeps showing up.

[image: annoying message]

How the heck do I get this thing to go away for good? I don't really care about hot code replace, my development cycle doesn't require it.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594408/how-do-i-disable-hot-code-replace-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Debug and you'll find the switches to control hot code swapping.